# font-awesome icons do not work in angular 10+

Tags: angular, font-awesome

So I used this website https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-use-font-awesome-icons-in-angular-10
did everything and that is the result. can not understand why some icons work and others do not.
P.S all of them are free icons [image]

```
<i class="fas fa-search fa-5x"></i>
<br>
<i class="fas fa-search-minus fa-5x"></i>
<br>
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-5x"></i>


<i class="fa fa-user fa-5x"></i>

<i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-5x"></i>

<i class="fa fa-money fa-5x"></i>

<i class="fa fa-home fa-5x"></i>

<i class="fa fa-th fa-5x"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which version of FontAwesome you're running. [v4.x](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/search) uses the `class="fa fa-search"` syntax while [v5.x](https://fontawesome.com/icons/search?style=solid) has different versions of an icon (ie `fas, far, fal or fad`).

Seeing how the former is working for you, I assume you've installed v4.x. Personally I'd recommend upgrading it, if only for the increased number of icons and more readable syntax.

Comment: I installed it using CLI in Angular .I thought it will install the latest version .

Comment: @medzvregena The package manager for v5.x has a bit of a different package name, see https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem I just found the solution

Just delete last letter from the first class and now it works

```
<i class="fa fa-search fa-5x"></i>
```

instead of

```
<i class="fas fa-search fa-5x"></i>
```